# I'm getting an `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments` for a sidekiq method that I added a parameter to. Any reason why this would be?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I'm using Sidekiq and I previously wrote a `perform` method that took in 3 parameters.

Needing to make an update, I added a fourth parameter, which is `override=false` (a parameter named `override` that defaults to `false`).

The issue is that every so often, I'm getting errors in my logs that look like `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 3)`. It's essentially looking for the old method definition with 3 parameters.

I have no idea why this is happening. Is there a way to maybe restart sidekiq or something?

Comment: What do you use for deployment?

Comment: using a service called Aptible. It's like Heroku.